# Spring security Basic authentication with Token authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to provide a Token based authorization for my Spring REST application which is currently based on Basic Authentication.

1. A Login/Token request (POST /path/to/login) => Do Basic authentication and return a token
2. All the other requests => Do a token authentication

How can I do that? 
(Spring 4.x)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Basic authentication flow, you must provide into request an Authorization header.

For example, if you have user=theuser and password=mypassword the header will be

> Key = Authorization ; Value = Basic dGhldXNlcjpteXBhc3N3b3Jk

where the string after Basic is the encoded string, theuser:mypassword, into base64. (check this https://www.base64encode.org/)

This header must be used for the end-points secured by BasicAuthentication.

An example of implementation:

1. Dependency:
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security
2. You must to create a configuration class and add annotations:

@Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity

```
public class MyWebSecurityCofiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("theuser").password("mypassword").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/path/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Stateless is used to not create a session and the user must send the Authorization header at every request. There are other 3 sessions modes:

- always – a session will always be created if one doesn’t already exist
- ifRequired – a session will be created only if required (default)
- never – the framework will never create a session itself but it will use one if it already exists

Answer (score 0):

Although the Spring Getting Started guide here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ relates to Spring Boot. It is pretty much applicable for basic Spring 4.x